# Не работает Normal Mapping (ну или Bump Mapping)

Tags: opengl, glsl, текстура

Не так давно наткнулся на урок по [Normal Mapping](http://learnopengl.com/#!Advanced-Lighting/Normal-Mapping) (ну или Bump Mapping) и решил повторить..

Ну так вот там есть интересный момент когда высчитываются нормали с поправкой на Bump из текстуры
происходит это..

5 строка в normal ложаться новые данные из бамп карты но она не перезаписывается почему ?!

Если кто то владеет информацией рад был бы послушать !

```
vec3 normal = normalize(fs_in.Normal);
if(normalMapping)
{
    // Obtain normal from normal map in range [0,1]
    normal = texture(normalMap, fs_in.TexCoords).rgb; //Она же должна  перезаписаться !!!!?? 
    // Transform normal vector to range [-1,1]
    normal = normalize(normal * 2.0 - 1.0);   
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего вам нужно скомбинировать нормали из текстуры с нормалями модели. Т.к. в текстуре нормали задаются относительно нормали поверхности рассчитанной обычным способом (такая текстура имеет обычно светло-голубой цвет R=0.5 G=0.5 B=1.0, что соответствует X=0 Y=0 Z=1). Для комбинирования также нужна информация об ориентации текстуры (где и нее перед, где право-лево). Это задается TBN векторами. В примитивных туториалах это часто опускается, т.к. рендер идет на плоский полигон расположенный перпендикулярно камере (TBN при этом вырождаются в "ноль").

В общем, приложите к вопросу картинку текстуры нормали и попробуйте найти более полный туториал.

Comment: Вы наверное не поняли сути вопроса я спрашивал почему функция texture не перезаписывает данные в normal помещённые ранние.
p.s у меня всё работает пруф выше добавил вместе с normal map.

Comment: @hays Почему вы так считаете, как должно выглядеть перезаписывание?

Comment: ну потому что указывается знак присвоение а не скажем *= или += данные должны исчезнуть и быть помещены новые из texture

Comment: @hays Еще раз, почему вы считаете что текущее поведение неправильное? Почему вы считаете, что "функция texture не перезаписывает данные в normal"?

Comment: Доказанно эксперементально если бы перезаписывало было бы заместо нормалей текстура нормалей а при указании конструкции
normal = texture(normalMap, fs_in.TexCoords).rgb получается комбинация 'мировых' нормалей с картой нормалей из текстуры

Comment: @hays Значит проверяйте код, где у вас идет подмешивание мировых нормалей - не могут же они сами по себе из воздуха браться.